# GPS security standards

Tags: mobile, wireless

Are there any GPS (global position) security standards to secure any kind of GPS implementation? For e.g GPS software coding standards, GPS traffic encryption standards? I asked because nowadays [there are attacks against GPS](http://www.wired.com/2012/07/drone-gps-spoof/all/) and i believe it will be getting common in the future

Comment: the military uses encrypted GPS, and anti-jam with multi-frequency signals

Comment: the article you link to explains that there isn't for commercial GPS ...

Comment: Short answer:
For U.S. & allied military use:  Yes, but the Pentagon flat out refuses to get into details (In the U.S. defense community there are classified subjects, and then there are **classified** subjects.  GPS anti-jamming & anti-spoofing measures are definitely in the latter category.)
For everyone else:  
Current, well-known bands: no. Bands that are new or planned for future service: maybe, arguably--http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/modernization/civilsignals/